# In RabbitMQ federation setup, will the downstream server receive the message published on the upstream server once network is restored?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm starting out on RabbitMQ so please forgive me if this is an elementary question.

I have Federation set-up between two servers. When the network is ok, then everything is fine, when we publish a message to the upstream server, the downstream gets the message.

My question is, what happens when the downstream server is down and a message gets published in the upstream one? Will the message be received by the downstream server once it starts back up or when the network goes back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's been over an year, I believe you've got your answer by now. But just to clarify to others who happen to visit this question, here's the answer

Exchange federation consumes messages from an upstream cluster and republishes on it's own local exchange, as if the messages published on the upstream cluster were published on the local cluster.

A situation where exchange federation could be used is when there are clusters in multiple regions, but you want to collect all messages to a central cluster where your consumers can process them. The federation act as an intelligent shovel, so it will create a queue on the upstream cluster, bind it to the exchange you're federating and then consume from that queue and republish them on the local exchange.

If the connection is broken, messages will queue up on the upstream queue and when the server reconnects again it will transfer all messages that were publish during the network outage.